# "Type RuntimeClass cannot be serialized" exception with HTTPClient on Windows Phone

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8, httpclient

I have an app that after the login page switches to a menu page where if I push the "start" button I get an exception. I do the login with the `HTTPClient` class. I only get the exception after the login.

This is the exception I get when I push "start":

> {"Type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass' cannot be serialized. 
>   Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, 
>   and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.
>   Alternatively, you can ensure that the type is public and has a parameterless constructor -
>    all public members of the type will then be serialized, and no attributes will be required."}

Comment: Are you saving some data after the login? Like, putting it into some state dictionary or something?

Comment: I added the error message to the title so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that after you login you try to serialize an object with a runtime class (e.g. SolidColorBrush) you can ignore these properties using the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute.